# Reduce pdf file size in .NET Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, pdf, optimization

We have a requirement to cutdown the generated pdf file size to 40% - 50%

Is there any available free library to code in .NET Core?

OR

Is there a way to reduce pdf file size in Microsoft Power Automate?

Comment: Could you please share few more details what you are up to now. As you may know The `System.IO.Compression` namespace contains the `ZipFile`,  `GZipStream` classes for compressing and decompressing files and streams. [`You can have a look on on our official document here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files)

Answer (score 0):

There are three possibilities here:

a) Your PDF files are inefficiently produced, and have duplicate information which can be removed losslessly; or

b) Your PDF files contain large images which you will need to resample to a lower resolution (for example, if your PDFs are scans); or

c) Your PDFs aren't really compressible further

If `cpdf -squeeze in.pdf -o out.pdf` gives you good results on your files, the answer is a). If not, it's b) or c).

Comment: We cannot control pdf size but what im really looking forward is to reduce file size by automation - by using a tool